# Maximum subsequence sum in an array with no 3 consecutive number

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

I have to find the maximum sum in an array such that no 3 consecutive number together
for eg
3 4 5 1 2
should return me 11. (4+5+2)

I am getting out as 9.
I am using dynamic programming since I want the running time to be O(N)
The idea is s array will store the max sum and s1 array will store the length of input seen to keep track of consecuent numbers

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ex {       

    public static int maxSubArraySum(int a[], int size)
    {

       int s[]= new int[size+1];
       s[0]=0;
       int s1[]= new int[size+1];
       s1[0]=0;
       for (i = 1; i <= size; i++)
       {

            s1[i]= 1+s1[i-1];
            if(s1[i]<3) {
                int k=Math.max(s[i-1], a[i-1]+s[i-1]);       
                s[i]=k;
            }
            else {
                s[i]=Math.max(a[i-1], a[i-1]+a[i]);
                s1[i]=0;
            }
       }
       return s[s.length-1];
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int size=sc.nextInt();
        int a[]=new int[size];
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
            a[i]=sc.nextInt();

        }
        System.out.println(maxSubArraySum(a, a.length));            

    }

}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Given is a sequence of distinct positive numbers. We want to find a subsequence with the
maximum possible sum, with the restriction that we are not allowed to take three consecutive
elements from the original sequence. For example, for input 1, 6, 5, 2, 7, 9, 3, 4, the
subsequence with the maximum possible sum is 6, 5, 7, 9, 4 (we have two pairs of consecutive
elements 6, 5 and 7, 9 but not three consecutive elements).

Comment: This still isn't a question. It's just a task you've been given. Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: in the eg of  3 4 5 1 2. My code is taking  3 4 2 and giving me 9. Where as it should give 4 5 2 =11. I think I am not properly finding out the max when I am at the third element in the array

Answer (score 2):

I think your code requires a slight tweak, below are the changes you need to make

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ex 
{       
    public static int maxSubArraySum(int a[], int size)
    {
       int s[] = new int[size+2];

       //they will form your base cases
       s[0] = 0;
       s[1] = a[0];
       s[2] = a[0] + a[1];

       for(int i = 2; i < size; i++)
       {
           s[i+1] = Math.max(a[i] + s[i-1], a[i] + a[i-1] + s[i-2]);
           s[i+1] = Math.max(s[i+1], s[i]); 
       }
       return s[size];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int size=sc.nextInt();
        int a[]=new int[size];
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++) 
        {
            a[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(maxSubArraySum(a, a.length)); 
     }           
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the array starts from index 0...n-1 i.e a[0...n-1],

we create `array table[n+1]` and `table[i]` means maximum sum from 1 to **i** without no three continuous numbers. While computing `table[i]`, we have to choose whether to select **i** th element or not.

So, three cases are there

Case 1: Since, we can't select three consecutive numbers, but can select two consecutive numbers and skipping third one.

Case 2: select **i** th element and skip **(i-1)** th element.

Case 3: If we doesn't select **i** th element

So, based on above discussion c++ code is given below:

```
int max_sum_no_three_consecutive(int a[], int n)
{
    int table[n+1];
    table[0] = 0;
    table[1] = a[0];
    table[2] = a[1];    
    for (int i = 3; i <= n; i++) table[i] = max_3(table[i-1], table[i-2] + a[i-1], a[i-1] + a[i-2] + table[i-3]); 
        return table[n];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an old post but thought of answering the question.

```
for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if(0 == i) {
        sum[i] = input[0];
    } else if(1 == i) {
        sum[i] = input[0] + input[1];
    } else if(2 == i){
        sum[i] = getMaxOf3(sum[i - 1], sum[i-2] + input[i], input[i] + input[i - 1]);
    } else {
        sum[i] = getMaxOf3(sum[i - 1], sum[i - 2] + input[i], sum[i - 3] + input[i] + input[i - 1]);
    }
}

int getMaxOf3(int x, 
                 int y, 
                        int z) {
    return Math.max(Math.max(x, y), z);
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
Consider the array: {3, 4, 5, 1, 2}
we need to first have some default values for the result array.
sum[0] = array[0];
sum[1] = array[0] + array[1];
sum[2] = maximum of either (arr[0] + arr[1]) or (arr[1] + ar[2]) or (arr[0] + arr[2])

We calculated 3 sums,as we will be using these for furthur sum calculations.
    sum[3] = max(sum[2], sum[1] + arr[3], sum[0] + arr[3] + arr[2]);
This reduces to,
sum[i] = max(sum[i - 1], sum[i - 2] + arr[i], sum[i - 3] + arr[i] + arr[i - 1]);
```